# Creating a Python Dictionary: Syntax Problems

Tags: python, syntax, dictionary

Hopefully this will be a quick solution.  I'm afraid that I don't quite know enough about Python to figure out why I'm having a compiler syntax error.  The code is as follows, and the compiler has an issue with the "for" statement in the line of code:

```
vocab_counter = {vocabLine.strip().lower(): 0 for vocabLine in vocabOutFile}
```

vocabLine is a line of text from a .txt document, and vocabOutFile is the file that it's reading from.  I am trying to create a list of the words in the .txt document and increment a counter on each word as they're found in a separate document.

So why is there a syntax error?

Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: Wrong python version and I didn't know it. I derped!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the bother.  I found out that what I was trying to do is only available in python 2.7 or higher.  For python 2.6 I had to change the code to:

```
vocab_counter = dict((vocabLine.strip().lower(), 0)
                     for vocabLine in vocabOutFile)
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Old python version, apparently.

Comment: @FeralShadow The code you've posted here creates a generator expression not a dict.

Comment: @Ashwini I'm unsure what that is, to be honest. Is that not what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: To create a dict use `dict((vocabLine.strip().lower(), 0) for vocabLine in vocabOutFile)`

Comment: Haha yes! Thank you!  That's what was missing you're awesome!